# python threading : cannot switch thread to Daemon

Tags: python, multithreading

I  would expect next code to be executed simultaneously  and all filenames from os.walk iterations , that got 0  at random , will get in result dictionary.  And all threads that have some timeout would get into deamon mode and will be killed as soon as script reaches end.  However, script respects all timeouts for each thread.

Why is this happening? Should it put all threads in backgroung  and kill them if  they will not finish and return result before the end of script execution? thank you.

```
import threading
import os 
import time 
import random

def check_file(file_name,timeout):
    time.sleep(timeout)    
    print file_name 
    result.append(file_name)

result = []
for home,dirs,files in os.walk("."):
    for ifile in files :
        filename = '/'.join([home,ifile])
        t = threading.Thread(target=check_file(filename,random.randint(0,5)))
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

print result
```

Solution: I found my mistake:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=check_file(filename,random.randint(0,5)))
```

has to be

```
t = threading.Thread(target=check_file, args=(filename,random.randint(0,5)))
```

In this case, threading will  spawn a thread with  function as object ang give it arguments. In my initial example, function with args has to be resolved BEFORE thread spawns. And this is fair.

However, example above works for me at 2.7.3 , but at 2.7.2 i cannot make it working.
I `m getting got exception that

```
function check_file accepts exactly 1 argument (34 is given).
```

Soulution :
in 2.7.2 i had to put ending  coma in args tuple , considering that i have 1 variable only . God knows why this  not affects 2.7.3 version . It was

```
t = threading.Thread(target=check_file, args=(filename))
```

and started to work with

```
t = threading.Thread(target=check_file, args=(filename,))
```

Comment: I think multiprocessing is better suited for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you were trying to do, but you're not using the right format for threading. I fixed your example...look up the Queue class on how to do this properly.

Secondly, never ever do string manipulation on file paths. Use the `os.path` module; there's a lot more than adding separators between strings that you and I don't think about most of the time.

Good luck!

```
import threading
import os 
import time 
import random
import Queue

def check_file():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        time.sleep(item[1])
        print item
        q.task_done()

q = Queue.Queue()
result = []
for home,dirs,files in os.walk("."):
    for ifile in files:
        filename = os.path.join(home, ifile)
        q.put((filename, random.randint(0,5)))

number_of_threads = 25
for i in range(number_of_threads):
    t = threading.Thread(target=check_file)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

q.join()


print result
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Queue is the next step  i`ll add when i understood how threading is working. For now  , i`m trying to keep code as much simple as possible, to visualize for myself how threading emchanics works.

Comment: You did it wrong. Queue is how you block threads. So, you queue up your data, start the threads you want then they pull objects from a queue. Your code will not work until you understand how `threading` works in general.

Comment: Sorry @blakev, i  started with next book  that explains threading without Queue class: Doug Hellmann Python Standard Library By Example  , so i`m trying to follow his steps.